# Condo Hardwood Install Advice

Tags: flooring, subfloor, hardwood-floor, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing

I am looking into installing new hardwood in my condo and have seen conflicting info on a few things that I could use clarification on.

The existing hardwood sits on some some 3/4" sleepers which are nailed to the subfloor, and has electrical conduit running between the sleepers. I've thought about just refinishing the existing 2 1/4" hardwood but I think this floor is in pretty bad shape. Noisy squeaks every step throughout, gaps between planks up to 1/8" in some spots, and some spots are very squishy and visibly deflect when stepped on.

I'm thinking about screwing the existing subfloor to the joists, replacing the sleepers with a layer of 3/4" OSB to avoid the hardwood spanning a gap, and screwing that osb to the original subfloor. Hoping this would reduce future squeaking. My understanding is that I should at least use a vapor barrier below the hardwood but have been looking into options that will deaden some sound. I've heard about mass loaded vinyl potentially being a good option, but have seen a variety of opinions ranging from it being great to total hoax.

My questions are:

Will replacing the hardwood with the system I am planning work to mitigate future squeaks? This is the main reason I am leaning towards replacing vs refinishing. Or would it be better to just accept the squeaks and refinish?

Since I will have a double layer subfloor, is it ok to run the hardwood parallel to the joists for aesthetic reasons?

Is mass loaded vinyl a good choice for sound deadening, will it work as a vapor barrier too, and can it be used with nailed hardwood? If no would I be able to use a typical underlayment used mostly for floating floors to help instead? Something like this: https://www.flooranddecor.com/underlayment-installation-materials/sentinel-protect-plus-600sqft-100987189.html

Also, my HOA is very loose with reno restrictions (self-run, small building) so I have the permissions to alter the floor, and there are no sound transmission requirements in our bylaws. Nevertheless, I'd like to do what I can without breaking the bank too much to deaden sound transfer to my downstairs neighbor.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By sleepers you mean pieces of wood placed like joists would be?  Maybe 14 inches between them.  That should cause most of the problems with the hardwood.

Comment: If you remove the sleepers to put in OSB, where will the conduit go?  Or am I misunderstanding your plan?

Comment: @Huesmann you're understanding correctly, I was just planning on making cutouts with a jigsaw to avoid the conduits.

Comment: @crip659 yes, they're 1 1/2" wide strips on top of the subfloor and they are supposed to be placed in line with the joists but from already having retiled the kitchen I know that they do not really sit on top of the joists, I assume that's a large part of the problem.